# Why does Linked List Node show the data in the Node as @data instead of data (in Locals window) - C#

Tags: c#, debugging, singly-linked-list

I have the following code:

```
using System;

namespace DataStructures
{
    public class Node
    {
        public Node next;
        public string data;
    }

    public class LinkedList
    {
        private Node head;

        public void printAllNodes()
        {
            Node current = head;
            while (current != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(current.data);
                current = current.next;
            }
        }

        public void AddFirst(string data)
        {
            Node toAdd = new Node();

            toAdd.data = data;
            toAdd.next = head;

            head = toAdd;
        }

        public void AddLast(string data)
        {
            if (head == null)
            {
                head = new Node();

                head.data = data;
                head.next = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Node toAdd = new Node();
                toAdd.data = data;

                Node current = head;
                while (current.next != null)
                {
                    current = current.next;
                }

                current.next = toAdd;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add First:");
            LinkedList myList1 = new LinkedList();

            myList1.AddFirst("Hello");
            myList1.AddFirst("Magical");
            myList1.AddFirst("World");
            myList1.printAllNodes();

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Add Last:");
            LinkedList myList2 = new LinkedList();

            myList2.AddLast("Hello");
            myList2.AddLast("Magical");
            myList2.AddLast("World");
            myList2.printAllNodes();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I was debugging the code and, in the Locals Window - the data variable in the Node shows up as `@data` instead of `data`.
Why does the `data` variable in the Node shows up as `@data` in the Locals Window?
In languages such as C/C++ - the Nodes `data` variable shows up as `data` in the Locals Window.
So why does C# show it as `@data`?

Comment: A reserved word in some context? In C#, you can declare variables and types with names using keywords, just prefix them with an @, like class @class.

Comment: @TanveerBadar, my thought too, but 'data' is not in any list of c# keywords

Comment: TanveerBadar, Yes, looks like some reserved word. I changed the name to data1 in the Node, and now it shows as data1 in the Locals Window, instead of @data1.

Comment: @TanveerBadar, Originally I thought that the Locals Window was showing `@data` - because the Method's also had a local parameter called `data`. I changed the Methods local parameters to `str`, but still the Node's `data` variable is showing up as `@data` in the Locals Window...

Comment: @pm100 Record types in C# 9 were originally declared as `data class`, OP doesn't say anything about the environment he's using so it could be a recent enough Roslyn version which has C# 9 support.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I am using Visual Studio 2009, .Net Framework 4.8, C# 7.3.